# eigenvalue bounds of $A^\top B+BA$ for symmetric $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
Is it true that
$$
\lambda_{\min}(A^\top B+BA)\ge \lambda_{\min}(A^\top +A)\lambda_{\min}(B),
$$
where $\lambda_{\min}$ indicates the minimum eigenvalue?
Do we have a similar inequality for the maximum eigenvalue?

—-

I raised a follow-up question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503832/eigenvalue-bounds-of-a-top-bba-for-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-b), where I imposed a positive definiteness condition on $B$.

Comment: In future, please avoid modifying your question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true even for $n=2$.

$$A=A^T=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \\ &-1 \end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & \\ & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then LHS $=-2$ and RHS $=2$.

At least, there should be a way to control the sign on both sides.

Comment: Thanks for your observation. Do you think the claim holds for positive semidefinite $B$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503832/eigenvalue-bounds-of-a-top-bba-for-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-b))?