# eigenvalue bounds of $A^\top B+BA$ for symmetric positive semidefinite $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
Is it true that
$$
\lambda_{\min}(A^\top B+BA)\ge \lambda_{\min}(A^\top +A)\lambda_{\min}(B),
$$
where $\lambda_{\min}$ indicates the minimum eigenvalue?
Do we have a similar inequality for the maximum eigenvalue?

---

According to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4503796/eigenvalue-bounds-of-a-top-bba-for-symmetric-b), the claim is not true without the positive semidefiniteness condition of $B$. Will the claim hold with this additional condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequalities
$$
\begin{cases}
\lambda_{\min}(A^\top B+BA)\ge \lambda_{\min}(A^\top +A)\lambda_{\min}(B),\\
\lambda_{\max}(A^\top B+BA)\le \lambda_{\max}(A^\top +A)\lambda_{\max}(B)
\end{cases}
$$
are false. Consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&0},\ B=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}
\quad\text{and}\quad A^TB+BA=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}.
$$
Since $B$ is singular, the RHS of the two inequalities are zero. However, as $A^TB+BA$ is a symmetric matrix with a zero diagonal, its minimum eigenvalue must be negative and its maximum eigenvalue must be positive. (Note that every PSD matrix is the limit of a sequence of positive definite matrices. Therefore the two inequalities above remain false even if $B$ is required to be positive definite.)

The reversed versions
$$
\begin{cases}
\lambda_{\min}(A^\top B+BA)\le \lambda_{\min}(A^\top +A)\lambda_{\min}(B),\\
\lambda_{\max}(A^\top B+BA)\ge \lambda_{\max}(A^\top +A)\lambda_{\max}(B)
\end{cases}
$$
are also false. Consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&1},\ B=\pmatrix{2&0\\ 0&1}
\quad\text{and}\quad A^TB+BA=\pmatrix{4&1\\ 1&2}.
$$
The eigenvalues of $A+A^T=2I+\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$ are $1$ and $3$. Hence $\lambda_{\min}(A^\top +A)\lambda_{\min}(B)=1$ and $\lambda_{\max}(A^\top +A)\lambda_{\max}(B)=6$. However, it is evident that $I\prec A^TB+BA\prec 6I$. Therefore $\lambda_{\min}(A^\top B+BA)>1$ while $\lambda_{\max}(A^\top B+BA)<6$.